# prepareForSegue sending data to tableview in a container view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I am sending data from one tableview list to another tableview used as a detail view for the selected cell. Simple -

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    if (segue.identifier == "EventDetailSegue") {
        let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EventDetailTableViewController
        var event : Event
        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        event = filteredEvents[index!.row]
        } else {
        event = events[index!.row]
        }

        detailVC.eventImage = event.image
        detailVC.eventCompany = event.company
        detailVC.eventName = event.name
        detailVC.eventLocation = event.location
        detailVC.eventPrice = event.price
        detailVC.eventPromoterImage = event.promoterImage
    }
}
```

Since I now want to have a static button bar on the bottom of the detail tableview. I need to change the EventDetailTableViewController to be in a container view on a UIViewController. So I can then simply do what I want inside the UIViewController.

My question is how do I still send this data to the now embedded EventDetailTableViewController inside the container view? Since the segue will now need to be going to the UIViewController with the container view, but I also need to make sure this data is passed to that TableView inside the container.

Comment: create an instance of EventDetailTableViewController  then set its data ,then pass it to UIViewController . in UIViewController viewdidload use the EventDetailTableViewController instance

Comment: Thanks will give this a go! What do you mean by in the viewdidload use the EventdetailTableViewController instance? After creating an instance and passing it to the UIViewcontroller via the segue, how would I then get it into the EventDetailTableViewController inside its container?

Comment: make the instance become a childcontroller  then put the tableview in the container view  you want

Comment: Why not just change EventDetailTableViewController to subclass UIViewController rather than UITableViewController.  You can then do everything you want in one VC.

Comment: At the moment I have class EventDetailTableViewController: ParallaxTableViewController. Which is a library I found of github. Could I still just simply subclass all of this into a standard UIViewController? Wilson could you give a code example to what you mean about the child controller I'm not too sure I understand :)

Comment: @MattPorter wait a moment,i'll post it

Comment: @MattPorter In that case, forget my comment - I would stick to using a container view.

Answer (score 0):

i use color instead of data :
`EventDetailTableViewController` ->`ViewController3`
`UIViewController` -> `ViewController2`
try like this :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let tableVc = ViewController3()
    tableVc.color = UIColor.redColor()
    let vc = ViewController2()
    vc.tableViewController = tableVc
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}

}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

var tableViewController:ViewController3!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    tableViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
    addChildViewController(tableViewController)
    tableViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
    view.addSubview(tableViewController.view)
    tableViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


}
}
class ViewController3: UITableViewController {

var color :UIColor!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = color
}
}
```

hope it be helpful :-)

Comment: Thanks I understand this now, for some reason though since putting this tableViewController as a subView. It is not recognising the cell identifiers. Very strange.. any ideas?

Comment: @MattPorter add this: tableViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self) ,i edited , if not work ,show me more detail